# ADF Mobile App in Samsung Tab 3 with Android 4.2 closes Suddenly (D/houdini Unsupported feature)

Tags: android, mobile, oracle-adf, samsung-mobile

I created a simple "Hello World" app in Jdeveloper and deployed it into my Samsung Tab 3 with Android 4.2.2. And when I touch the App to open it, it loads for a short moment and then I'm redirected to the Apps section. My app never opens.

This is the simple Html that my feature has:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></meta>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
```

I Deployed it to my Nexus Tab, Android 4.1 and it worked perfectly, buy it doesn't work on my Samsumg Tab 3, Android 4.2. I checked the logs with Logcat, these are the messages I think that could be related to what happen:

```
D/CVM     (22824): CVM Configuration:    
D/CVM     (22824):  Java stack chunk size (stackChunkSize):    
D/CVM     (22824): 2048    
D/CVM     (22824):  Java stack minimum size (stackMinSize):     
D/CVM     (22824): 3072    
D/CVM     (22824):  Java stack maximum size (stackMaxSize):     
D/CVM     (22824): 131072    
D/CVM     (22824):  CPU affinity mask (cpuMask):     
D/CVM     (22824): 0    
D/CVM     (22824):  Reduce Signal Usage (noSignals):     
D/CVM     (22824): false    
D/CVM     (22824): JIT Configuration:    
D/CVM     (22824):  Interpreter transition cost (icost):     
D/CVM     (22824): 20    
D/CVM     (22824):  Mixed transition cost (mcost):     
D/CVM     (22824): 50    
D/CVM     (22824):  Backwards branch cost (bcost):     
D/CVM     (22824): 4    
D/CVM     (22824):  Compilation threshold (climit):     
D/CVM     (22824): 20000    
D/CVM     (22824):  When to compile (compile):     
D/CVM     (22824): policy    
D/CVM     (22824):  What to inline (inline):     
D/CVM     (22824): none    
D/CVM     (22824):    
D/CVM     (22824):  Max Inlining Depth (maxInliningDepth):     
D/CVM     (22824): 12    
D/CVM     (22824):  Max Inlining Code Length (maxInliningCodeLength):     
D/CVM     (22824): 68    
D/CVM     (22824):  Min Inlining Code Length (minInliningCodeLength):     
D/CVM     (22824): 16    
D/CVM     (22824):  Policy Triggered Decompilations (policyTriggeredDecompilations):     
D/CVM     (22824): true    
D/CVM     (22824):  Max Working Memory Size (maxWorkingMemorySize):     
D/CVM     (22824): 1048576    
D/CVM     (22824):  Max Compiled Method Size (maxCompiledMethodSize):     
D/CVM     (22824): 65535    
D/CVM     (22824):  Code Cache Size (codeCacheSize):     
D/CVM     (22824): 524288    
D/CVM     (22824):  Upper Code Cache Threshold (upperCodeCacheThreshold):     
D/CVM     (22824): 95%    
D/CVM     (22824):  Lower Code Cache Threshold (lowerCodeCacheThreshold):     
D/CVM     (22824): 90%    
D/CVM     (22824):  Pass Phi values in registers (XregisterPhis):     
D/CVM     (22824): true    
D/CVM     (22824):  Pass locals in registers between blocks (XregisterLocals):     
D/CVM     (22824): true    
D/CVM     (22824):  Compiling Causes Class Loading (XcompilingCausesClassLoading):     
D/CVM     (22824): false    
D/CVM     (22824):  Patched Method Invocations (Xpmi):     
D/CVM     (22824): true    
D/CVM     (22824):  Trace (trace):     
D/CVM     (22824): none    
D/CVM     (22824):     
D/CVM     (22824): GC[SS]: Initialized semi-space gen for generational GC    
D/CVM     (22824):  Size of *each* semispace in bytes=16384000    
D/CVM     (22824):  Limits of generation = [0x7e267000,0x801a7000)    
D/CVM     (22824):  First semispace      = [0x7e267000,0x7f207000)    
D/CVM     (22824):  Second semispace     = [0x7f207000,0x801a7000)    
D/CVM     (22824):  Current semispace    = First semispace    
D/CVM     (22824): GC[MC]: Initialized mark-compact gen for generational GC    
D/CVM     (22824):  Size of the space in bytes=36044800    
D/CVM     (22824):  Limits of generation = [0x801a7000,0x82407000)    
D/CVM     (22824): GC[generational]: Sizes    
D/CVM     (22824):  youngGen = min 16384000 start 16384000 max 16384000    
D/CVM     (22824):  oldGen   = min 9830400 start 36044800 max 114688000    
D/CVM     (22824):  overall  = min 26214400 start 52428800 max 131072000    
D/CVM     (22824): GC[generational]: Auxiliary data structures    
D/CVM     (22824):  heapBaseMemoryArea=[0x7e267000,0x86f07000)    
D/CVM     (22824):  cardTable=[0x86f07000,0x86f4d500)    
D/CVM     (22824):  objectHeaderTable=[0x86f4e000,0x86f94500)    
D/CVM     (22824):  summaryTable=[0x86f95000,0x870ae400)    
D/houdini (22824): [22861] Unsupported feature (ID:0x20900143).    
F/libc    (22824): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdead0000 (code=1), thread 22861 Thread-1828)    
I/DEBUG   ( 1884): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***    
I/DEBUG   ( 1884): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifixx/santos10wifi:4.2.2/JDQ39/P5210XXUAMFA:user/release-keys'    
I/DEBUG   ( 1884): Revision: '8'    
I/DEBUG   ( 1884): pid: 22824, tid: 22861, name: Thread-1828  >>> om.company.BassicApp2 <<<    
I/DEBUG   ( 1884): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr dead0000    
I/DEBUG   ( 1884):     eax 00000000  ebx 7dee65f4  ecx 65cf965c  edx 00000000
```

I think the key must be here (fatal signal means there is a null pointer):

```
D/houdini (22824): [22861] Unsupported feature (ID:0x20900143).    
F/libc    (22824): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdead0000 (code=1), thread 22861 Thread-1828)
```

Comment: Do you have any Logcat, or the code that you made? And what `Theme.Parent` did you choose?

Comment: I Dont have any Logcat. I only created a Mobile Application in Jdeveloper, then I added a feature containing a Html page with a Hello World Label.
Then I deployed it into my Android emulator and it worked fine. So, I tried deploying it to my Samsung Tab 3 and the App never loaded, when I tried to open it I was redirected to the Apps section after a few seconds.
I do not know what is Theme.Parent for...

Comment: This mays be cause of many things: bad path of library, not deploying for your version on Tablet (minSDKversion...), like I said the Theme declared in your `Style` not allowing with your sdk version... If you can, I think, show the code that you made could help us to help you. What's your version on Tablet of android and what have you declared like `android:minSdkVersion` & `android:targetSdkVersion` in your manifest?

Comment: Actually I did not declared anything in my manifest, this is the only thing my manifest contains: Manifest-Version: 1.0.
Actually I deployed the app in my Nexus tablet Android 4.1 and it worked.
I eddited the text, adding more info. I really apreciate the time you are spending on this.

Comment: Actually, with ADF Mobile App, you haven't to fill in your `style.xml` or your `manifest.xml` like I do with other softwares. But I think, this exception `java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed` is a clue. I really don't know, and maybe it's a mistake, but I saw a similar issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14562. Hope this help, my knowing in your case is not sufficient, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is the atom cpu that is not supported. The jvm that ships with ADF Mobile doesn't work on this.
ADF mobile only supports ARM. Perhaps in future versions this will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Houdini is an ARM instruction set translator. And the Samsung Tab 3 10.1 has Intel Atom processor. The problem must be around this.

Answer (score -1):

I found this:
**ADF Mobile only supports the ARM EABI v7a System Image.**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/deploying.htm

I wonder if there will be a way to make ADF work in my Tab